# Is there a simple table structure update procedure for a manipulated PostGIS layer under QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing

I have an intensive data exploring session using Postgresql/PostGIS as a backend and try to explore the results using QGIS. Within QGIS I have a defined a "complex" style to show the results. Sometimes it is nessesary to add data fields, for filter options or calculations for example. Unfortunatly are the adoptions not present in the current layer, loaded in QGIS.  Is there a simple way to refresh the table structure/content without removing, adding and restyling the existing vector layer?

Answer (score 0):

Add the column in Postgres, save the QGIS project, close QGIS and re-open the project.

The new column will be readily available.